# Batch: Receive output from arduino from Serial port to CMD (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, batch-file, serial-port

I have an Arduino where I would like to send an command to the command prompt. 
My solution to the problem would be to make a batch program that listen to the serial port and then runs the command, but I do not know how to do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a console application you can write a console application in, e.g., C# with Visual Studio and start the application via CMD.

The application itself, can listen and print out all incoming serial data. I would recommend you to use the bidirectional serial connection library, called [CmdMessenger](https://github.com/thijse/Arduino-Libraries/tree/master/CmdMessenger). The usage is quite straightforward and there are several [examples and documentation](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/CmdMessenger) resources on the web. I think you can easily adapt the examples for your application scenario.